# JOLT Chainr expects a JSON array of objects - Malformed spec

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am competely newto JOLT and I wanna just play [in this sandbox](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) with the test json that I have found. But whatever I do always get error:

> JOLT Chainr expects a JSON array of objects - Malformed spec.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

JSON sample:

```json
{
  "Photos": [
    {
      "Id": "1234",
      "Caption": "photo 1",
      "Sizes": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "Url": "http://test.com/0001/1234/photoThumb.jpg",
          "Id": "thumbnail"
        },
        "normal": {
          "Url": "http://test.com/0001/1234/photo.jpg",
          "Id": "normal"
        }
      },
      "SizesOrder": [
        "thumbnail",
        "normal"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "5678",
      "Caption": "photo 2",
      "Sizes": {
        "thumbnail": {
          "Url": "http://test.com/0001/5678/photoThumb.jpg",
          "Id": "thumbnail"
        },
        "normal": {
          "Url": "http://test.com/0001/5678/photo.jpg",
          "Id": "normal"
        }
      },
      "SizesOrder": [
        "thumbnail",
        "normal"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My spec:

```
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "Photos": {
      "*": {
        "Id": "photos[&1].id",
        "Caption": "photos[&1].caption"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Because, you just missed the wrapper square brackets which should surround the current spec. eg. `[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "Photos": {
      "*": {
        "Id": "photos[&1].id",
        "Caption": "photos[&1].caption"
      }
    }
  }
}]` .  Btw, you can add an expected output to the question as well.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  Thank you!! Funny thing is I did tried square brackets but it didn't work. But when I copied and past your example somehow it started work :)